# How do I remove the last comma in a range of printed prime numbers in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a self taught beginner.

I've been trying to solve the following problem in my code for hours:

```
lower = int(input("Enter the start of the range:"))
upper = int(input("Enter the end of the range:"))
if (lower < 2 or upper < 2 or lower>upper):
  print("Wrong value entered.")
else:
 print("Prime numbers between", lower, "and", upper, "are" , '' ,end='')
 for num in range(lower, upper + 1):
       for i in range(2, num):
           if(num%i) == 0:
              break
       else:
           print(str(num) +",",end='')
print('\b' +".")
```

The code works fine when I run it in an online compiler and prints the output neatly like:

`The prime numbers between n1 and n2 are m1,m2,m3.`

But when I run it my local compiler, it "prints" the backspace without actually moving cursor and replacing the last comma.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what is the operational system of your local environment? did you try to use the `\r` on the last print?

Comment: @EduardoColtri, I'm using PyScipter a remote debugger and no \r doesn't work.

Comment: I don't see the problem when I run the code.  Start = 2, end = 35 prints the following: "Prime numbers between 2 and 35 are 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31."  Isn't this what you want?

Comment: @itprorh66 Oh really? For me in my local compiler it prints a unicode backspace and then a fullstop, I guess my compiler is bad, anyway thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would go about it, using the [`join`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/join-function-python/) function:

```py
lower = int(input("Enter the start of the range:"))
upper = int(input("Enter the end of the range:"))

def is_prime(n):
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n%i==0:
            return False
    return True

if lower < 2 or upper < 2 or lower > upper:
    print("Wrong value entered.")
else:
    primes_between_lower_and_upper = (str(n) for n in range(lower, upper + 1) if is_prime(n))
    print(f"""\
Prime numbers between {lower} and {upper} are \
{', '.join(primes_between_lower_and_upper)}.""")
```

Comment: Wow, this code is so efficient and works so well. Just a question what does print(f"""\ for in the beginning.?